# Uber token request returning javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: uber-api

Hi when I try to get a token from Uber's API (https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token), I get the below exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

My code used to work a week or more ago and now it doesn't. Nothing has changed on my end. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Did you have any recent updates on the java version on your side? You can check some SO articles about the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=handshake_failure

Comment: java -version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Other https connection work through the same code base. I think the problem is on Uber's side...

Comment: Can you please provide more information what you are trying to do and how you actually do it. Without this info, we are unable to trace the problem you are having. Also, it is impossible to answer without seeing a stack trace and possibly the output produced when running client or server with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading to a newer version of java on my elastic beanstalk instance. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading to a newer version of java on my elastic beanstalk instance. Thank you for your help.